# How to select the last created object in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this path in S3: `object1/object2/object3/object4/`

In `Object4/` I have a list of objects, example:

```
directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/2022-30-09-15h21/

directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/2023-20-12-12h30/

directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/2022-31-12-09h34/

directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/2023-12-08-14h56/
```

I would like to select the last created directory in `directory4/` then I should download all files inside it.

I wrote this script to do it:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime 

session_root = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-3', profile_name='my_profile')
s3_client = session_root.client('s3') 

bucket_name = 'my_bucket' 

prefix = 'object1/object2/object3/object4/'

# List objects in the bucket 
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix) 

# Extract the object names and convert them to datetime objects 

objects_with_dates = [(obj['Key'], datetime.strptime(obj['LastModified'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) for obj in response.get('Contents', [])] 
# Find the latest created object 

latest_object = max(objects_with_dates, key=lambda x: x[1]) 

print("Last created S3 object:", latest_object[0]) # the returned value is: object1/object2/object3/object4/2023-20-12-12h30/my_file.csv
```

My script select the last created directory in `directory4/` and download the last created file inside, the result of my script is: `directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/2023-20-12-12h30/my_file.csv`

But I would like to download all files inside.

Do you have an idea please how can I modify my script to select the last created directory in `directory4/` and I download all files inside ?

Thanks

Comment: You say "I would like to select the last created object", but you also say "I would like to download all files inside" -- these appear to be contradictory requirements. Do you want to download a single file which is the "last created object", or do you want to download "all files inside", and what do you mean by "inside"?

Comment: Or are you saying that there is a CSV file in the bucket and that CSV file contains a list of object names, and you then wish to download all objects whose names are listed in the CSV file?

Comment: I want to downlad all files in the last created object

Comment: My PATH is the same that I specified in my question, but I have more then 4 objects in object4/, this is just an example.

Comment: Ah! Are you saying: Find the directory (Prefix) with the latest date in its name and then download all files in that directory (Prefix)? That is, you are NOT wanting to find the OBJECT with the latest creation date, you are wanting to find the DIRECTORY with the latest date in its name and then download the objects within it. So in your example, you would want to download all objects in `2023-12-08-14h56/`? Is that correct? If not, please use A LOT more words to explain what you are seeking because it hasn't been clear in the previous three questions you've asked on the same topic.

Comment: Exact ! this is that what I want, select the last created directory exist in directory4/ with the latest date in its name and then download all files in this directory. In my example the last created directory in directory4/ is : 2023-20-12-12h30/ , because the format is: YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: Can I ask... How often would you be running this code? If your actual goal is to continually download the objects that were not downloaded in previous executions, you could instead use the `aws s3 sync` command -- it will download ALL files, but it is smart enough to only copy files that it has not previously copied. So, it is a very efficient way to 'synchronise' the files from S3 to a local directory.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the date format in your directory names (eg `2022-30-09`) are in `YYYY-DD-MM` format? This is an unusual format because the ISO standard is normally `YYYY-MM-DD`, which has the benefit for automatically sorting in date order. It would be much easier if dates were in `YYYY-MM-DD` order -- is this under your control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your requirement is:

- List all sub-directories for a given prefix (eg all sub-directories under `directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/`)
- Of those sub-directories, find the sub-directory that represents the latest date by using the **name of the subdirectory** that includes a timestamp in `YYYY-DD-MM-HHhmm` format
- Download all the objects in that sub-directory

Here is a sample program that uses the list of `CommonPrefixes` returned by S3, which is effectively a list of sub-directories.

```py
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my-bucket'
PREFIX = 'directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/'

# Custom date sorter to handle YYYY-DD-MM-HHhmm format
def date_sorter(date):
    date_parts = date.split('-')
    return (date_parts[0], date_parts[2], date_parts[1], date_parts[3])


# Obtain a list of CommonPrefixes in the given Bucket and Prefix
# Use a paginator in case there are more than 1000 objects
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET, Delimiter='/', Prefix=PREFIX)

# Get the 'latest' CommonPrefix but it is in the format YYYY-DD-MM-HHhmm
prefixes = [item['Prefix'] for item in result.search('CommonPrefixes')]
latest_prefix = sorted(prefixes, key=date_sorter)[-1]

# Download all objects from that prefix
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
for object in s3_resource.Bucket(BUCKET).objects.filter(Prefix=latest_prefix):
    # Download to local directory using just the filename
    filename = object.key.split('/')[-1]
    print(f'Downloading {object.key}')
    object.Object().download_file(filename)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked well. How can I add a local folder where I store the files ?

Comment: Python has a `os.makedirs()` command.

Answer (score 0):

A way to select the last created object into your S3 Buckets will be to create DynamoDB and use a Lambda with S3 Object Lambda to save a catalog into DynamoDB and place the index on the modified/change time.

Ofc you can use an other database then DynamoDB but DynamoDB is very cheap to start with and later you can think about what makes sens by changing DB, DynamoDB only costs when you use it if you use that option.

It's a little bit more complex than you asked for, but if you have 100.000.000 objects in your S3 you will need to pay for each list scan and object lookup so it can be very expensive if you make mistakes so I will recommend you to use S3 Object Lambda ( https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/object-lambda/ )

Comment: I already wrote a code, I would like to help me and correct it. And I don't have a DynamoDB

Comment: I updated my question, in fact my script select already the last created object in object4/ but it  download only one file, I would like to download all files, could you please help me, thanks.